# Convert .arw Sony photo to .raw file

Tags: c#, jpeg, photo, sony

I want to convert a photo (shooted with Sony digital camera, .arw) in a Raw file and / or jpeg. Is there any library that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [WIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component).  Windows Imaging Component comes with WPF, so your project would need to start there if you want the library by default.

There are several examples using WIC.  [Resizing images](http://keyvan.io/image-resizing-with-windows-imaging-component-in-net), [Copying metadata](http://www.dustyfish.com/blog/copying-jpeg-metadata-using-c-and-windows-imaging-component), or [Convert to different formats](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/66fa2da4-8352-448d-93b2-b64c9b99e6d3/need-to-use-wic-to-convert-any-image-file-format-file-to-bmp-file)

You will need the [Sony RAW codec](http://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/www/download/vista_raw/) to open the arw file.

Comment: is there any example of "conversion" in c#?